# jQuery get YouTube video src from iframe code

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I am trying to get the youtube src from from within an iframe embed code and pass it as a variable.

For example, if my youtube embed code is:

```
<iframe width=&quot;1024&quot; height=&quot;576&quot; src=&quot;https://www.youtube.com/embed/rfxESg1_hEA?feature=oembed&quot;frameborder=&quot;0&quot;allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I'm trying to get https://www.youtube.com/embed/rfxESg1_hEA

Is there a way to do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var src = $("iframe").attr("src").split('?')[0];
alert(src);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe width=&quot;1024&quot; height=&quot;576&quot; src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rfxESg1_hEA?feature=oembed&quot;frameborder=&quot;0&quot;allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```